# Paperclip, uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::Fog::Excon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, paperclip

I just installed paperclip on Ubuntu with rails 3.2.9 and I cannot upload images. 
The message I get is uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::Fog::Excon.

Any explanation for this?

Comment: little bit of code would help here, like your model, controller, form you are using to upload the image etc

Answer (score 7):

Install the gem at your machine:

```
gem install fog
```

And add Fog gem at your Gemfile:

```
gem 'fog'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that the Fog gem is included in your Gemfile, or ensure that you aren't configuring the use of Fog if you don't need it. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1071) for the same error message, in this case Fog was included but not available in all the groups needed within the Gemfile (it should probably be in the root of your Gemfile and not group specific).